# Returning to an activity (but not through finish())

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, android-intent, return

as the title states, how do I return to an activity that has been started but not by calling finish(). I'm primarily concerned about this because I don't know how to tell a Notification to return to the original activity that created it when a user pulls down their notification bar and clicks on the notification. The [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) on how to create a notification only explains how to launch a new activity after it is clicked on.

Is there some kind of Intent call that can do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use getIntent(), instead of creating a new Intent.

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,  getIntent(), 0);
.....
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
```